# Mail function working properly on localhost but on godaddy server sending email on junk

Tags: php, laravel

I am have having Go daddy shared hosting, in which we are running laravel php system.
Now when we are sending email using Mail::send it is ending up in junk.

here is my ENV file details

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.rediffmailpro.com  
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=xxx@domain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=xxx@domain.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="xxx@domain.com"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Test Name"
```

Are we using proper setting, or Godaddy should use different setting

Comment: It is not the problem of coding, and there is no solution available.

Comment: No solution????

Comment: email recieved via sg2nlsmtp01.shr.prod.sin2.secureserver.net instead of smtp.rediffmailpro.com , may be this could be the reason

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no solution. Read this (https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?hl=en)

Comment: Both smtp.rediffmailpro.com and sg2nlsmtp01.shr.prod.sin2.secureserver.net are on MX blacklists (google `mx blacklist check` and then pick a check site and you will find the information

Answer (score 0):

There could be several issues with mail ending up in the junk folder.

1. the server from where the mail is sent is on a blacklist
2. your mail is being bounced too often and therefor you're marked as spammer
3. your dns settings are not set to allow mail send from the rediffmailpro.com servers. If you want to allow those, add the correct spf records to do so

Comment: How to add correct spf record for that

Comment: depends on the domain, but you should have had info from rediffmailpro concerning what the spf settings should be.
https://support.rediffmailpro.com/article/spf-and-dkim-setup/
Don't forget to add the dkim record as well